# Как добавить кнопку оперативного заказа в wordpress на woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Как сделать кнопку быстрого заказа на сайт на woocommerce в wordpress на главной странице? То есть посетитель интернет-магазина заходит на сайт, нажимает на кнопку и пишет имя, адрес и телефон и нажимает заказать и всё.

Comment: а там есть ответ? нет

Comment: А товар-то какой он при этом заказывает?

Comment: никакой. просто пишет имя, телефон и адрес. а потом ему звонят и с ним обсуждают об заказе услуги.

Comment: типо кнопки заказа товара в один клик, только без заказа

Comment: а в чем смысл для покупателя? рассказать магазину о своем существовании?

Comment: ну сам магазин по ремонту обуви и смысл кнопки в вызове курьера

Comment: Тогда просто форма обратной связи.

Comment: заказчик говорит, что форма обратной связи это форма обратной связи, а нужно именно заказ, заказ курьера

Comment: назовите эту форму ЗАКАЗ КУРЬЕРА большими буквами сверху)

Comment: Или нужен виртуальный товар "заказ курьера", чтобы он остался в системе магазина?

Comment: ну кнопка "заказ курьера" должна быть на главной странице, а не в разделе услуг и товаров

Comment: Да без разницы, где она. Можно сделать виртуальный товар "заказ курьера" и повесить его на кнопку.

Comment: а можно сделать виртуальный товар "заказ курьера" на главную страницу в самом начале? если да, то как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавить кнопку заказа виртуального товара "Вызов курьера" можно следующим образом:

```
<a class="btn" href="http://example.com/shop/?add-to-cart=xxxx">Вызвать курьера</a>
```

Где `exampe.com` - ваш домен, `btn` - ваш css класс для кнопки, xxxx - id товара (не sku, а id записи типа product).

Посмотреть работающий пример можно [тут](http://igrolog-school.ru/start-speak-moskow/).

На этом сайте еще установлен плагин [WooCommerce Direct Checkout](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-direct-checkout/), который отправляет сразу на страницу оформления после выбора товара.

Answer (score 1):

Подойдет любая форма обратной связи. Напр [CF7](https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/)

А если корзина и тд не нужна, то вообще применение WC избыточно.